# Inferring populations from larger ones

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, sampling

I have an interesting problem, I am trying to estimate populations (ages mostly) of users who visit my website - I have IP->ZipCode->Census demographic information (which gives me an age distribution per zip). Now clearly this site, which is geared towards young people, is a much smaller subset than the entire population of any given zip code.

More specifically, I am interested in how these populations change per blog post / sub-page.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction, or specify which techniques might be helpful here.

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of different ways you could approach solving this problem. One that comes to mind is the use of "confidence intervals" which estimate the true number of patrons visiting your site.

Comment: It sounds like a lost cause: you have "noise" of age-independent Zip-post correlation which is likely higher than "useful signal" of age-post correlation.

Comment: Well, actually the volume of traffic is pretty big, and the census information breaks it down into 4 year intervals for age. So I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I'm not sure exactly how. My background is pretty quantitative but it's been a number of years since I've had my head in that space.

Comment: Perhaps some sort of bootstrapping, sampling sub-groups of all traffic, and looking at the variance there? Not sure.